# How to slice an array and add it to a string url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an array of strings that I would like to append to a url in an ajax request. There are some additional string that i need to add to the Url along with the array string.

html

```
<ul>
  <li data-url="string1"></li>
  <li data-url="string2"></li>
  <li data-url="string3"></li>
  <li data-url="string4"></li>
  <li data-url="string5"></li>
</ul>
```

So far in my javascript i have something like this:

javascript

```
//create empty array
var data = [];

$('ul li').each(function(){
  data.push(this.getAttribute('data-url'));
})
// now in data I have : ['string1','string2', 'string3' ..]

// here is where im lost
// how to concat those array items into the url with the '&'  symbol
var url = 'www.foo.com/bar=' data + '&'

//Make an ajax request
$ajax({
  url: url,
  method: 'POST',
 })
```

overall I would like the url to look something like this:

```
www.foo.com/bar=string1&bar=string2&bar=string3
```

Comment: Wouldn't that overwrite previous `bar` values? Don't you mean `bar[]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something simple like this,

```js
// using map iterate and get data value
var data = $('ul li').map(function() {
  return 'bar=' + $(this).data('url');
  // using data() you can get data attribute value
}).get().join('&');
// using get() you can get retuned value as an array
// joing the array using join()

var url = 'www.foo.com/' + data;

console.log(url);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li data-url="string1"></li>
  <li data-url="string2"></li>
  <li data-url="string3"></li>
  <li data-url="string4"></li>
  <li data-url="string5"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try an alternate like following

```
var data = "";

$('ul li').each(function(){
  data += "bar="+this.getAttribute('data-url') + "&";
})

data = data.substring(0, data.length-1);

var url = 'www.foo.com/' + data;

//Make an ajax request
$ajax({
  url: url,
  method: 'POST',
 })
```